# how to filter the date range in asp.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

My application contains two drop down lists: startTime and endTime. If I select the startTime 10 AM and endTime 12 PM , the application should then block the following ranges because they overlap:

```
10AM-11AM
11AM-12PM
11AM-1PM
```

What logic can I use in in asp.net/SQL Server that fulfills these conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but you should be able to parse the values in to datetime & compare them.

Comment: Hey, you have to monitor the database to see if the overlap already exists... so you have to write a database query to figure that out.  Please post some more detailed code if you need help with a specific part of this task, but we can't help write the code.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx for details of how to parse a string into a datetime. less than (>) is overriden on this class so just compare them. If I'm still missing the point, see @Brian above

Answer (score 0):

You should add those times/dates into a datetime variable. The datetime variable will have an array of functions to manipulate, format and work with the time in the datetime object.

Datetime var keep complete date and time. You can work with, or extract, jsut the date,time,hour,minute,day etc etc from the object and work with it if neccecary.

You should always take any time/date to a datetime and work with it in there. .net takes care of a load of date and time functionality included in the datetime object.

Browse around with intellisense on a datetime object, and see whats available that might help you with your solution.

You can parse a string into datetime like this:

```
dim mydate as datetime = DateTime.Parse("#1/1/1990 12:01:00 AM#")
```